# Question about Renormalization of Ghosts in QCD in MS scheme

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics, singularities

During a calculation of the Renormalization constant of the ghosts in QCD I stumbled over the following question:

When I calculate the self-energy of the Faddeev-Popov ghosts in $SU(N)$ non-abelian gauge theory ($N=3$ => QCD), I get, after dimensional regularization, the following expression:

$$-i\Sigma(p^2)=\frac{iNg^2}{16\pi^2}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\bigg (\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-\operatorname{ln}\bigg(\frac{-p^2x\overline{x}}{\widetilde{\mu}^{2}}\bigg)\bigg )p^2\overline{x}-i(Z-1)p^2$$

where $g$ is the coupling constant, p is the momentum of the incoming ghost (and therefore by the overall delta-function also of the outgoing anti-ghost), $\widetilde{x}=1-x$, as always in Feynman parametrisation and $Z$ is the normalization constant of the ghosts, e.g. $c_{Bar}=\sqrt{Z}c_{ren.}$.

When I use now the MS-scheme, I get

$$Z=1+\frac{g^{2}}{16\pi^2\varepsilon}\frac{N}{2}$$

This should be right, because I found the same expression in various books (e.g. Schwartz)

Now to my question: In the end the goal of renormalization is to make all the diagrams finite. But if I want to compute some scattering processes, then I have always (according to the LSZ formula) to consider the **on-shell** amputated Green-functions. But in this case, I would get into trouble, because $\mathrm{ln}(p^2)$ will become infinite, since the ghosts are massless and therefore $p^{2}=0$. So my question is, why don't we absorb this term into our renormalization constant? Where is my thinking error?

Comment: Sounds like a call for an infrared regulator.